# sharing internet between network interfaces

Tags: networking, internet, lubuntu, network-bridge, nat

I have a laptop with lubuntu 11 with two network interfaces, wireless and wired. Wireless interface connects to the router with DHCP and provides access to the internet. The wired interface has a staic ip address from a different range for internal LAN. I would like to allow computers on the LAN get access to internet using laptop's wireless connection. What are my options here? Do I need a bridge, NAT, firewall?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lubuntu comes with Network-manager, which makes this very easy. Click on the network icon in your panel, and select Edit connections.

[image: Edit Network]

In the dialog that appears, select the wired interface and click Edit. In the IPv4-settings pane in the new dialog, you can select Method: "Shared with other computers".

[image: Share IPv4]

Any internet connection will now be shared on your wired connection, complete with DHCP.

Comment: Thant did not seam to work right away. Do I need change any other settings of the interface, like ip or mask, or do I need to have some settings done on all other LAN clients?

Comment: what does setting this "Shared with other computers" in the gui tool actually does? Can I make the same change by editing some config file manually?

Comment: You may need to restart the host. (The computer that shares the connection). I'm not sure. The clients doesn't need to do anything other than use DHCP.

Comment: Would this work even if "The wired interface has a staic ip address from a different range"? Wouldn't that make some problems?

Comment: @rubo77: I don't think that should be a problem. It uses a router and a dhcp server, pretty much like your wireless router at home.